# Any way to accept special characters without delimiters in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I'm tasked with a making a shell script that swaps 2 strings and then outputs a file.  The commands are similar to:

> sed s/**search_for**/ **replace**/g output.txt > temp.dat
>
> mv temp.dat output.txt

The script works like this:

```
./myScript var_A var_B output.file
```

Which I got to work fine.  The second part does the same thing, but I must treat the following special characters as regular strings:

```
[ ] ^ * + . $ \ -
```

I have a general idea on how I want to tackle this (this may be the wrong way).  I want to accept those characters and set them as variable with a \ appended in the front.

```
var_A=\\$1
var_B=\\$2
```

My issue is with the * (asterisk) and \ (backslash) characters.  I'm using a simple **test script** to see what parameters I can easily convert to a variable:

```
for i in "$@"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

But the * char shows all the files in the directory and \ shows the next argument.  I know about **set -o noglob** and **set -f**, but those will not work for me (and doesn't work on the script).  I also know that you can escape using a backslash but I can't use that either.  I must be able to take a special character (even * and /) and convert to a string.  I hope this all makes sense and someone can help me.

Comment: How do you pass the parameters? You should use quotes: `script.sh '*' '\'`, also `for i in "$@"` and `echo "$i"`.

Comment: The issue is the script must be able to accept arguments even without quotes (at least I think it does, I don't really know what my instructor wants :/ so I just want to cover my bases)

Comment: You're talking enough about your intended implementation that I don't understand the **actual goal** you're trying to accomplish. Escaping things for sed is different from escaping things for shell in general, and the Right Answer is typically not to use sed at all.

Comment: To be more clear -- "take a special character and convert to a string" is not a useful/meaningful phrase. If you're reading something in from NUL-delimited input, and always quote correctly on expansion, you can handle any valid C string without it changing behind your back. So, you're doing something very specific wrong if you're getting contrary behavior to that, and you'll have to show us what you're doing with enough specificity to figure out exactly what it is that's wrong before we can give an optimal answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you put patterns in variables, then you use these variables in `sed`, and you need to treat the patterns as literal strings, without their special meaning in regular expressions?

If so, then before passing the patterns to `sed`, you need to escape the special symbols. Here's a possible implementation with my tests:

```
#!/bin/sh

escaped() {
    echo "$1" | sed -e 's/[].+-[$\\^*]/\\&/g'
}

set -- [ ] ^ \* + . \$ \\ -
for pat1; do
    pat2=$(escaped "$pat1")
    echo "$pat1 was $pat1" | sed -e s/$pat2/_/
done
```

The `escaped` function takes the argument and puts a backslash in front of special characters. The loop demonstrates that the `pat2` variable generated this way correctly matches the special characters in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform literal replacements, `sed` is the wrong tool for the job.

See the awk script given in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021. Quoted here:

```
# usage: gsub_literal STR REP
# replaces all instances of STR with REP. reads from stdin and writes to stdout.
gsub_literal() {
  [[ $1 ]] || return
  awk -v str="${1//\\/\\\\}" -v rep="${2//\\/\\\\}" '
    BEGIN { len = length(str); }
    {
      out = "";
      while (i = index($0, str)) {
        out = out substr($0, 1, i-1) rep;
        $0 = substr($0, i + len);
      }
      out = out $0;
      print out;
    }
  '
}
```

...which can be used as...

```
tempfile=$(mktemp "$file.XXXXXX")
gsub_literal "$search" "$rep" \
    <"$file" \
    >"$tempfile" && \
  mv -- "$tempfile" "$file"
```

with absolutely any values for `$search` and `$rep`.

Perl is also well-suited for operations of this type, having in-line replace functionality and (unlike sed) the ability to refer directly to its argv array or environment variables for literal search or replacement values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote your patterns on the shell's command line. You can't work around that.

Perl regular expressions give you a "quotemeta" function that treats every character as literal

```
perl -e '
    $str = q{this is a string with **emphasis**};
    $pattern = q{**emphasis**};
    $repl = "characters";
    $str =~ s/$pattern/$repl/;
    print $str
'
```

```
Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE *emphasis**/ at -e line 5.
```

but

```
perl -e '
    $str = q{this is a string with **emphasis**};
    $pattern = q{**emphasis**};
    $repl = "characters";
    $str =~ s/\Q$pattern\E/$repl/;
    #.........^^
    print $str
'
```

```
this is a string with characters
```