# trouble with 'sed' in sh script

Tags: regex, unix, sed, pipe, sh

I'm trying to write a script to swap out text in a file:

```
sed s/foo/bar/g myFile.txt > myFile.txt.updated
mv myFile.txt.updated myFile.txt
```

In the shell, I would evoke the sed program, which swaps out text in myFile.txt and redirects the changed lines of text to a second file. mv then moves .updated txt file to myFile.txt, overwriting it.

I need to watch out for "special characters" though so I'm using a regular expression to do that.

I wrote:

```
#!/bin/sh
#First, I set up some more descriptive variables for my arguments    
initialString="$1"
shift
desiredChange="$1"
shift
document="$1"
#Then, I evoke sed on my document to change all 'special characters' into
#'/special charachters'
updatedDocumentText=`sed 's:[]\[\^\$\.\*\+\-\?\\\\/]:\\\\&:g' $document`
#below, I'm checking my work
echo $updatedDocumentText
#Now, I make that 'new string' the output of a program (echo) and pipe that
#output to sed
finalDocument=echo $updatedDocumentText | sed 's/$initialString/$desiredChange/g'
#Checking my work
echo $finalDocument
#Now this string has to be the output of a program so I can use the
# redirect operator. I'm using echo as the program again.
echo $finalDocument > $document
```

There are two problems. The most important is: the second sed thinks that the text in the string $updatedDocumentText is the name of a file. I've been working on this for longer than experienced programmers would be able to believe and I'm at the end of my rope with this. The above configuration gave me the clearest errors out of everything I tried. I'm at the end of my rope, please save me if you can.

The second, trivial problem, is my regular expression doesn't replace '\' but it works on all of the other special characters.

Comment: linked with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20387539/redirecting-in-a-shell-script

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot the special quotes, or the `$()` syntax:

```
finalDocument=$(echo $updatedDocumentText | sed "s/$initialString/$desiredChange/g")
```

To replace a backslash, you have to double them, like:

```
sed 's/\\/\\\\/g' infile
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, I tried that actually a few hours ago with hilarious results. It searches and replaces properly but it leaves all of the backslashes! I mean, does sed have a problem with special characters or doesn't it? it made no sense. As for he second thing, you'll notice in my code, I have all the backslashes you recommend.

Comment: @user3067517: Add to your question an input string with backslashes, your expected output and the way in which your `sed` command doesn't work. It's easier for me to test a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an intermediary file, you can do replace strings in-place using the `-i` flag:

```
sed -e s/foo/bar/g -i myFile.txt
```

Instead of reading an entire file into a variable and then echoing it, use pipelines: modify the input and pipe the output to the next command. So instead of:

```
updatedDocumentText=`sed 's:[]\[\^\$\.\*\+\-\?\\\\/]:\\\\&:g' $document`
finalDocument=echo $updatedDocumentText | sed 's/$initialString/$desiredChange/g'
echo $finalDocument > $document
```

This is "sort of" equivalent:

```
sed -e 's:[]\[\^\$\.\*\+\-\?\\\\/]:\\\\&:g' -e "s/$initialString/$desiredChange/g" -i "$document"
```

I say "sort of", because you made several other misakes in your code:

- In `sed 's/$initialString/$desiredChange/g'` you used single quotes, so the variables are not interpolated there, so this command most probably replaced nothing.
- In `echo $updatedDocumentText`, some of the escaped special characters will not be preserved, which could have been fixed by double quoting: `echo "$updatedDocumentText"`

Finally, I think what you really want to do is escape the special characters in `$initialString`, not in the file content. So I think this is what you're looking for:

```
escaped=$(echo "$initialString" | sed -e 's/[].+-[$\\^*]/\\&/g')
sed -e "s/$escaped/$desiredChange/" -i "$document"
```

All the quoting is significant there and serves a purpose. The `-e` flags for `sed` are not really necessary, but I like to put them always to make it perfectly clear that it's an expression, not a filename argument.

About replacing special characters, [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313505/any-way-to-accept-special-characters-without-delimiters-in-a-shell-script/20313780#20313780) might be interesting for you too.